# How to design header and footer with background image in flutter?

Tags: flutter

[image: anyone help me.how to design like below image. any sample. i am new for flutter developement]

**how to create design look like below image. any sample please send**

Answer (score 0):

what's so tough in this?

The header can be a simple AppBar. The left, you can arrange it like this:

```
SingleChildScrollView -> Column

-> Container -> Image

-> Row/Wrap/Grid -> Buttons

-> Footer
```

In other words, you can achieve this layout in the easiest way with just one column widget and it's children.

Comment: ok thanks i try. problem page scroll time background image also scrolling. i need background image and footer fixed mode

Answer (score 0):

```
 return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Header'),
        flexibleSpace: const Image(
          image: NetworkImage('https://picsum.photos/700/300'),
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
      ),
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: const Text('Body'),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: NetworkImage('https://picsum.photos/700/300'),
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
            child: const Text('Footer'),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

See the result **[here](https://dartpad.dev/?id=8f4efd1089d28992f96ec23eef7bf149)**.